# dockerizing Spring Boot Application error: Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-image

I'm starting working with docker and I'm trying to dockerize my Spring boot Application. I generated this using spring initializr. I'm working with maven. My DockerFile looks like this:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

WORKDIR /usr/app

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

It's pretty simple.

I executed the next commands:

```
docker build -t shortenurl .
```

I can see the image in the console with docker images:

[image]

But when I try to run the image with the command: `docker run -p 8080:8080 shortenurl` I got this error message: Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar

I've tried different configurations but not pretty sure. Any advice?

Thanks.

This is my plugin pom.xml plugins section:

```
       <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

This is my log after the command:docker build -t shortenurl .

```
$ docker build -t shortenurl .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  32.89MB
Step 1/5 : FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> 3fd9dd82815c
Step 2/5 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
 ---> 248aa4be697d
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /usr/app
 ---> Running in 5fcd71c548af
Removing intermediate container 5fcd71c548af
 ---> bc344b970b11
Step 4/5 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in 46b4e4f8e9b7
Removing intermediate container 46b4e4f8e9b7
 ---> 6b4f55a86a23
Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
 ---> Running in 838a6052f4c8
Removing intermediate container 838a6052f4c8
 ---> 7d7d272ea42d
Successfully built 7d7d272ea42d
Successfully tagged shortenurl:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  For instance, if you get a debugging shell in the image, is the `app.jar` file actually in the image root directory?

Comment: your `app.jar` might not be executable. Can you show your `pom.xml`, specifically `spring-boot-maven-plugin`?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I edited my question with the plugin section.

Answer (score 0):

You're building with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` but you're not generating an executable jar. Update your plugin's configuration to:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, I updated the question with the log after the command: docker build -t shortenurl . Thanks!

Comment: Sorry totally mistaken the issue for another one. I'm guessing your `COPY` operation is not going well. What's the use of `docker-maven-plugin` if you're building with `docker` itself?

Comment: @rasilvap Can you try `FROM java:8-jdk-alpine

COPY target/app**.jar /usr/app/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/app/app.jar"]` and make sure your jar file is actually copied.